# Grouped array gets empty (Lodash's groupBy does work though)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

Here is the sample plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/bJFmT0WlRfqUgrCxZRT6

To start with: I am grouping a collection by a certain key - in my example yob.

I have two options -

- I can write a custom function that does the job (which I want to do as I can add custom logic)
- I can use _.groupBy provided by lodash/underscore.js

So I decided to try both the methods - using lodash I group the collection by a key and output is displayed (see plunkr)

When I use the custom method, `studentsByYear` in this case, somehow the array becomes empty before being displayed. I have console logged my output before returning the array and the array has the desired output ..

So my question is why my grouping method does not work? Am I missing something obvious in angular? Is it that I have to do a deep copy of objects before I return them, if yes please explain?

---

```
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <h2> Using Lodash </h2>
    <ul ng-repeat="(yob, students) in myModel.studentsByYobLodash">
      <h3>{{ yob }}</h3>
      <div ng-repeat="s in students">
        <p> {{s.name}} </p>
      </div>
    </ul> 

    <h2>Not using Lodash </h2>
    <ul ng-repeat="(yob, students) in myModel.studentsByYob">
      <h3>{{ yob }}</h3>
      <div ng-repeat="s in students">
        <p> {{s.name}} </p>
      </div>
    </ul> 
  </div>
```

### script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.factory('studentsFactory', [function () {
  var students = [{
    name: 'Tony',
    yob: '1987'
  },{
    name: 'Rachel',
    yob: '1988'
  }, {
    name: 'Eric',
    yob: '1988'
  }, {
    name: 'Jon',
    yob: '1988'
  }, {
    name: 'Tim',
    yob: '1989'
  }, {
    name: 'Bing',
    yob: '1987'
  }, {
    name: 'Valerie',
    yob: '1988'
  }, {
    name: 'Brandon',
    yob: '1987'
  }, {
    name: 'Sam',
    yob: '1987'
  }]

  return {
    getStudents: function () {
      return students;
    }
  }
}])

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'studentsFactory', function ($scope, studentsFactory) {
  $scope.myModel = [];
  $scope.myModel.students = studentsFactory.getStudents();

  $scope.myModel.studentsByYobLodash = studentsByYearUsingLodash($scope.myModel.students)
  $scope.myModel.studentsByYob = studentsByYear($scope.myModel.students);

  function studentsByYearUsingLodash (students) {
    return _.groupBy(students, 'yob');
  }

  function studentsByYear(students) {
    var arr = [];
    angular.forEach(students, function (student) {
      var key = student.yob;
      _.has(arr, key) ? arr[key].push(student) : (arr[key] = [student]);
    })

    return arr;
  }
}])
```

Comment: Try changing `var arr = [];` to `var arr = {};` because you are using `(yob, students)` key, value in your ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the structure you have you are using `key, value` with object iteration in ng-repeat. So by sending `myModel.studentsByYob` as an array will eventually return an array with holes, because you will end up having, for instance, myModel.studentsByYob[0..] as undefined as they don't exist and the array object instead has property 1987, 1988 etc which points to the array of students and if you check the browser console you will see the exact same error pointed by the ng-repeat code because of multiple undefined keys returned. So just change:

```
var arr = [];
```

to

```
var arr = {};
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CQvL6w4En86kkGtCPdbp?p=preview)

Comment: Ouch that was the issue! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when you create the `arr` in `studentsByYear()`:

```
var arr = [];
```

should be

```
var arr = {};
```

Angular iterators treat arrays and objects differently, so when iterating on a non-zero-indexed array, using (key, value) will always result in an unset key. Since Angular thinks `undefined == undefined`, it results in a duplicate key error.

---

Incidentally: you theoretically could get away with this error exactly once, so if your yob's were:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4...] instead of [1987, ...]
```

you would not have had an error, just an empty "0" at the top of your list.

http://plnkr.co/edit/VPiJSjOqPNFeunc7LUqJ?p=preview

But once you have 2 out-of-sequence indices

```
[2, 3, 4...] // 0 and 1 are missing
```

then you will again get the error, because `0 == undefined` and `1 == undefined`, therefore `0 == 1` and it's a duplicate error.

Comment: Makes sense .. I don't know how I missed it. Thanks!